# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil... Only on device not in the simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have created a button, that replaces another button once it is pushed. The code works fine in the simulator. But not on the device. As soon as I press the doneButton I get the following **error**:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

So the didPushEditButton function works, but not the didPushDoneButton function...and that appears only on an iPhone not in the simulator.
xcode  7.3
iOS 9.3
Swift 2.2

The error appears after line,

> self.editButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func didPushEditButton(sender: UIButton)
{
    self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    self.editButton.removeFromSuperview()
    self.lowerNavView.viewWithTag(18)?.removeFromSuperview()

    self.doneButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    self.doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainViewController.didPushDoneButton), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllTouchEvents)
    self.doneButton.setTitle("done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.doneButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
    self.doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(8, 10, 74, 30)
    self.doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.0, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.doneButton.tag = 17
    print(self.doneButton.tag)
    self.lowerNavView.addSubview(self.doneButton)
}

func didPushDoneButton()
{
    self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    self.lowerNavView.viewWithTag(17)?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.editButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)

    self.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainViewController.didPushEditButton(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllTouchEvents)
    self.editButton.setTitle("edit", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.editButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
    self.editButton.frame = CGRectMake(8, 10, 92, 30)
    self.editButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.editButton.tag = 18
    self.lowerNavView.addSubview(self.editButton)
    }
```

Comment: Try deleting the app on the iOS device and simulator and running a clean in the Xcode project (command shift k). Then re-run the app on both devices. Xcode 7.3 has had some weird bugs when running an app on an actual device.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem remains the same. Works in the simulator, not on the device...

Comment: Found a solution (or better a workaround). Just created all buttons programmatically and everything works fine...dont know why but it does.